# What does M mean in Mercurial's hg status output

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Mercurial and I've modified a file in my local computer.
`hg status` returns

```
M settings.py
```

But now I don't want to commit changes and I want to take back my file before last changes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use hg update -C to update all tracked files to the working branch.

If you only want to revert a specific file use hg revert filename

Comment: You can use the http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PurgeExtension to clear out all ignored and untracked files